# Ubuntu 18.04 LTS Operating System not detecting external mouse and keyboard?

Tags: 18.04, keyboard, mouse

When I connect an external keyboard and mouse in USB slot before the operating system runs, then my operating detects it and it works fine.

But, when I connect the keyboard and mouse after operating system runs, it is not detecting my keyboard and mouse.

I am facing this issue in Ubuntu 18.04 LTS version, not on the Windows 10 operating system.

How can I fix this issue?

Comment: Please try `lsusb` or `sudo lsusb` this should refresh usb ports and tell us what it does

Comment: Its showing device id but device not working.
`Bus 001 Device 014: ID 046d:c03d Logitech, Inc. M-BT96a Pilot Optical Mouse`

Comment: maybe something to tune in the bios setting about pointers